# Algorithm for game similar to Sokoban

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I'm looking for some direction for an algorithm I'm working on. The game is very similar to the Sokoban game.

We have a board where each position is either an empty space or a wall. There are two robots each occupying an empty space. In a single move, the robot can move along a direction parallel to the axes of the board until it hits a wall or other robot. A robot cannot stop midway.  There are two targets that the robots are trying to get to, it doesn't matter which robot reaches with target location. Once a robot reaches a target, it can go help the other robot. When we are finished, both robots must be occupying a target location. We're aiming for O (M*N)^2 time-complexity, where M*N is the size of the board.

I'm assuming we will need to use some sort of graph algorithm (BFS/DFS).

I'm not sure where to begin my research, so if anyone has any input or can provide me any links to read that would be wonderful.

Comment: Start from BFS and DFS algorithms. A simple recursive DFS can do this, probably. I am just not sure about time complexity since there are two robots and the answer can be polinomial..

Comment: I'd say you start with BFS, which, is used to find shortest paths from source to destination.

Comment: @vish4071 that is a good idea, BFS is probably the way to go here. I just keep getting hung up on the two robot idea where one is capable of assisting the other if necessary.

Comment: just find shortest paths for robots (R1,R2) for targets (T1,T2) in 4 ways, R1-T1, R1-T2, R1-T1 (through T2) and R1-T2(through T1) and similar for R2. Then its just simple to find which way is the best.